# Replace square-braced placeholder with new text

Tags: php, regex

I've this URL:

```
https://example.com/[photo-s]/photo.jpg
```

Sometimes the part between `[]` changes.

How in PHP, can I replace this part with another thing ?

Example:

```
preg_replace('photo-[a-z]', 'newphotopath', 'photo-s');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = 'https://example.com/[photo-s]/photo.jpg';
preg_replace('~\[(.*?)\]~', 'something_new', $url);
```

->

```
https://example.com/something_new/photo.jpg
```

If you mean to replace everything between `.com/` and the following `/` regardless of having brackets or not you could use:

```
preg_replace('~.com\/(.*?)\/~', '.com/something_new/', $url)
```

->

```
https://example.com/something_new/photo.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

### Code

```
$target = 'https://example.com/[photo-s]/photo.jpg';
$result = preg_replace('/\[photo-[a-z]+]/', 'somethingElse', $target);
```

### Output

```
string(43) "https://example.com/somethingElse/photo.jpg"
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/0aKDS).